# How to move free space from end of vm disk to resize(grow) primary partition on qemu hypervisor?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, size, parted

I was able to add space to my vm, but am at a loss for how to shuffle it from the end of the disk to resize the primary partition.  Appreciate your input if you are knowledgeable about how to do this...

For clarification... I am trying to move the free space on nbd0 at the end of the vm drive to grow the primary partition at partition 1.  How do I shuffle the free space over to partition 1?  I know I need to used parted, but I want to make sure I know the proper sequence of commands for the reshuffle...

```
$sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/nbd0 "print free"

*the current image (after tinkering)

Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/nbd0: 56.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags

        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space

 1      1049kB  25.7GB  25.7GB  primary   ext4            boot

        25.7GB  25.7GB  1048kB            Free Space

 2      25.7GB  46.2GB  20.5GB  extended

 5      25.7GB  26.8GB  1140MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

        26.8GB  46.2GB  19.3GB            Free Space

        46.2GB  56.9GB  10.7GB            Free Space
```

Comment: Are you trying to move the VMs disk partitions around, or the hosts? I don't think the question is clear on this point. Could you edit your question and clarify which system(s) you're moving data and partitions around on?

Comment: revised the question - thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

found the answer, if you have gparted on the system, you can use:

```
$gparted /dev/nbd0
```

after you have mounted your vm image as a block device